# Moving columns into new rows

Tags: excel, vba

I hope this is better, thank you!

My spreadsheet has the following columns:
Name / Address / Postcode / contact 1/ contact 1 salutation / contact 2 / contact 2 salutation / contact 3 / contact 3 salutation

Example:
John Smith / 2 salisbury rd / NW3 2PB / jane / Mrs Jane / Mike / Mr Mike / Lena / Ms Lena

I'd like to transfer it to a new sheet on the same file that would do the change the rows that do have contact 2 and 3 to be on their own rows like below:

Name / Address / Postcode / contact / contact salutation

John Smith / 2 salisbury rd / NW3 2PB / jane / Mrs Jane

John Smith / 2 salisbury rd / NW3 2PB / Mike / Mr Mike

John Smith / 2 salisbury rd / NW3 2PB / Lena / Ms Lena

How can do that please? I've managed to copy the full row when values contact 2 or 3 are not empty, but that's it...

Thank you so much!

Grazi

Comment: Suggest you read the HELP pages for [How do I Ask a Good Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and also, especially,  [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Then edit your question to provide more information so as to help us help you.

Comment: Sorry, I struggled to explain it, I had a look at the text and hope this is better? Thank you

Comment: Sounds like something you should be able to do easily with Power Query.  Just merge each pair of `contact/contact salutation`; Select the first three columns and **UNPIVOT** other columns; then split the previously merged columns and Rename them.